# Android slow sliding menu when using background images

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I'm using a sliding menu library from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu It works just fine except for one small thing: when I attach sliding menu to an activity that has an image as a background it starts lagging. When I swipe right or left it takes a few moments for the menu to respond. Has anyone seen this before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using a png image about 650 Kb in size, but I aslo tried using low quality pics of less than 20 Kb but the problem remained.

My min SDK is 13, target SDK is 17 ( I also tried changing those values, but it did not help)

This is the layout of one of my activities that uses sliding menu:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/my_background"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
```

if I remove the android:background value the menu slides just fine

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. This is an alternative to SlidingMenu. Android [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) provides a similar widget call [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html).

Comment: Any one have the solution for this issue

Answer (score 2):

You should add a separate background image for each drawable folder (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and so on). I tested having only one image in the basic drawable folder, it was opening and closing very slowly and not at all smoothly. If you add background images of different sizes to all the drawable folders it works like a charm.

Comment: You are my hero!  The sliding menu sluggish drove me crazy for a month,  i added all images to mdpi, hdpi and so on, everything is working properly!, thanks again and +1 for you!

Answer (score 0):

If someone (like me) still have the problem with sliding-menu and background image I try to explain how I fix this problem. The @netis solution didn't help me.
As you know problem go away if you not using background in slide menu, so we need to use something else instead of standart android background. I use `TextureView` for this.
In my xml for menu I added:

```
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/menu_texture_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In activity code when initialize menu added:

```
final TextureView texture = (TextureView) menuView.findViewById(R.id.menu_texture_view);

    final Drawable picture = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_background);

    texture.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            Canvas canvas = texture.lockCanvas();
            picture.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            picture.draw(canvas);
            texture.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    });
```

Basically we put our background into `TextureView` instead of using standart android ways (`android:background`, `imageVew` etc).

Also as recomendation you need to add backgrounds for all dpi (mdpi, hpdi, ...) for better performance.

I know it's ugly solution but it works for me when nothing other didn't help...